# System.Data.EntitySqlException: The argument types 'Edm.String' and 'Edm.Int32' are incompatible for this operation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I had to change the data type of one parameter in my query and now I am getting the error message outlined in the title of this message.  I've been trying to figure out what the problem is and it the only thing I can come up with is that since one parameter of the query is a number and the other a string, this is causing the problem.  Unfortunatly I'm very new to the entity framework and don't know how to adjust my query to fix this problem

Here is the query I am using:

```
var Item = (DataContextFactory.GetDataContext().Items.Include("Category")
                 .Where("it.CategoryID == " + categoryId + " && it.itemID == " +
                 itemId)).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @hvd my bad, completely forgot about Object Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one is string you forgot `''`

try this: (I dont know which one is string. In this example categoryId is string)

```
.Where(string.Format("it.CategoryID = '{0}' and it.itemID = {1}", categoryId, itemId))
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at your entity framework code file you will see class named like "SomethingContext" and then  try this code:

```
YourDBContext ctx = new YourDBContext();

var item = (from c in ctx.Category
               where c.CategoryID == categoryId && c.itemID == itemId
                select c).SingleOrDefault();
```